# Remind user to complete task on Windows 10

Tags: scheduled-tasks, reminder

I am using Windows 10 (x86) and I would like to set up a reminder to turn off wireless mouse at shutdown. So basically just a customised output message that pops up at shutdown. Best of all would be that computer doesn't actually switch off until I click "Ok" but that's not essential.
I know this question has already been solved for Windows 7, but the interface is very different. I am not an expert user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show notifications in Windows 10 using a powershell script:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730952.aspx

```
[void] 

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

$objNotifyIcon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon 

$objNotifyIcon.Icon = "C:\Scripts\Forms\Folder.ico"
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = "Info" 
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "Please turn off your wireless mouse" 
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Battery life reminder"

$objNotifyIcon.Visible = $True 
$objNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(10000)
```

How to run scripts when shutting down the computer has already been answered on stackoverflow, so I will only link it here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434863/executing-a-batch-script-on-windows-shutdown

I had not yet the chance to test it, so I do not know, if the notification will be visible long enough.

gpedit.msc is part of Windows 10 Professional or better. There are unofficial ways to install it manually though.

Comment: To install gpedit see my question & answer [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](//superuser.com/q/1018145)